# Flutter Integration Test: Fails on second screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

I wrote a basic Integration Test and had problems getting it to work.
Basically I have a main screen that has a `ÌconButton`. If clicked it opens a secondary screen.

My test looked like this:

```
  group('end-to-end test', () {
    testWidgets('test settings', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      appmain.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      final Finder settingButton = find.byTooltip('Settings');

      // Button is fine
      expect(settingButton, findsOneWidget);
      
      // Button is tapped -- a new screen should open
      await tester.tap(settingButton);

      // "Host" should be on the second screen, HOWEVER this test FAILS
      expect(find.text("Host"), findsWidgets);
    });
  });
```

So the question was: If the Button is successfully tapped, why does the test still fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you tap the `ÌconButton` in the integration test there is still an animation -- just like if you tapped the button in production. Because the animation is still going on, the test `expect(find.text("Host"), findsWidgets)` fails because it can't find anything. The solution is to **wait for the animation to finish** by calling `await tester.pumpAndSettle()` before calling the failed line.

---

***Side note:*** I also tried using `press` instead of `tap` but this only caused new issues because `press` is something different in the conext of mobile apps. You most likely want to use `tap`.